# To print a pattern in Python using 'for' loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I tried various programs to get the required pattern (Given below). The program which got closest to the required result is given below:

**Input:**

```
for i in range(1,6):
    for j in range(i,i*2):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print( )
```

**Output:**

```
1 
2 3 
3 4 5 
4 5 6 7 
5 6 7 8 9
```

**Required Output:**

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
```

Can I get some hint to get the required output?

Note- A newbie to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the printed value outside of the loop, then increment after its printed

```
v = 1
lines = 4
for i in range(lines):
    for j in range(i):
        print(v, end=' ')
        v += 1
    print( )
```

Comment: Hey, what does this `print()` do? I don't get how we shift to a new line using `print()`.

Comment: Well, you had that in the original question. By default, that prints a new line character.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to keep track of the count and solve this mathematically and be able to directly calculate any n-th line, the formula you are looking for is the one for, well, [triangle numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number):

```
triangle = lambda n: n * (n + 1) // 2
for line in range(1, 5):
    t = triangle(line)
    print(' '.join(str(x+1) for x in range(t-line, t)))
# 1
# 2 3
# 4 5 6
# 7 8 9 10
```